# Rails bootstrap select2 is not loading properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( 'select' ).select2();
});
```

When entering the dropdown,it shows two different boxes as one shows dropdown field and another one shows select 2 text suggestions.I have searched a lot.but could

```html
.form-group
  %label.cols-sm-2.control-label{:for => "company_type"}
  .cols-sm-10
    .input-group
      %span.input-group-addon
        %i.fa.fa-user.fa{"aria-hidden" => "true"}

        = p.select(:company_type, User::COMPANY,{}, {:class => "form-control ",prompt: "Select Your Business"})
```

'nt find the exact solution.

Comment: have you included the select2 stylesheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require select2 in application.js and application.css

```html
*= require select2 (application.css)
//= require select2 (application.js)
```